# Not able to create first program in Eclipse with Selenium using Appium

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, automated-tests, appium

I am not able to do automation testing with Appium server by using Eclipse with Selenium. I have shared below Eclipse error and Appium server logs also. I have shared Eclipse error also as below:

> Error: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag

Please check below code in Eclipse:

```
package tests;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class StartChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "7970dc54"); // Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "9 PKQ1.180904.001");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        // Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {

            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> Driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(
                    new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This question is pretty broad, and doesn't contain discernible error messages or a clear question.  This might help: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @JimHayes sir, please check now i have edited my Problem again, let me know if you need any kind of information...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't actually started your Appium server yet. You can't instantiate a new AndroidDriver without starting the Appium server.

Above the line `// Set the Desired Capabilities`, add this:

```
        // start appium service
        AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        AppiumLocalService _appiumLocalService = builder.UsingAnyFreePort().Build();
        _appiumLocalService.Start();
```

You'll also need to update the line

`AppiumDriver<MobileElement> Driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);`

to

`AppiumDriver<MobileElement> Driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(_appiumLocalService.ServiceUrl, caps);`

That way, you are using the correct service URL that you Appium service was started on.

Additionally, you should also make sure the following settings on your Android device are also enabled:

- Developer mode `ON` -- tap build number 7 times
- USB Debugging `ENABLED`
- Select USB configuration -- change from `Charging` to `Picture Transfer Protocol` or `MIDI`

Make sure your device is appearing when you run `adb devices` command. I only needed to enable the first two options -- developer mode & USB debugging -- to get mine working.